# Empty User Object in nextAuth JWT Callback

Tags: next-auth

I am trying to adjust my JWT and Session callbacks to attach properties to my browser session, but I can't seem to figure out what is being returned incorrectly which is leading to my JWT callback having an undefined user. I am using a JWT session strategy and custom login page.

Here is a log of JWT and Session callbacks:

```
JWT Callback {
  token: {
    name: 'John Doe',
    email: 'test@test.com',
    iat: 1678918901,
    exp: 1681511921,
    jti: '4e1b6c12-68f0-4009-8497-b2fa6a3bbb7e'
  },
  user: undefined
}
Session Callback {
  session: {
    user: { name: 'John Doe', email: 'test@test.com', image: undefined },
    expires: '2023-04-14T22:26:51.318Z'
  },
  token: {
    name: 'John Doe',
    email: 'test@test.com',
    iat: 167891221,
    exp: 1682510921,
    jti: '4e1b6c12-68f0-4009-8497-b2fa6a3bbb7e'
  }
}
```

Here is the authorize:

```
async authorize(credentials) {
        console.log(credentials);
        const email = credentials.email;
        const password = credentials.password;
        const formPassword = credentials.formPassword;
        const authFormType = credentials.newUser ? formPassword : password;

        try {
          if (!email || !password) {
            console.log('No Email or Password Provided');
            return null;
          }

          const user = await prisma.appUsers.findUnique({
            where: {
              email: email,
            },
          });

          if (!user) {
            console.log('User does not exist');
            return null;
          }

          const isPasswordValid = await confirmPasswordHash(
            authFormType,
            user.password
          );

          if (!isPasswordValid) {
            console.log('Password is not correct');
            return null;
          }

          return {
            email: user.email,
            name: user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName,
            // id: user.id,
            // newUser: credentials.newUser,
          };
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
        }
      },
```

Callbacks:

```
callbacks: {
    session: ({ session, token }) => {
      console.log('Session Callback', { session, token });
      return session;
    },
    jwt: ({ token, user }) => {
      console.log('JWT Callback', { token, user });
      if (user) {
        // console.log('user', user);
      }
      return token;
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user is `undefined` in the jwt callback, how do you explain that the `token` and the `session` are correctly updated from the response?

> The session callback is called whenever a session is checked. By default, only a subset of the token is returned for increased security. If you want to make something available you added to the token (like access_token and user.id from above) via the jwt() callback, you have to explicitly forward it here to make it available to the client.

so at some point the user was defined and available in the jwt callback to update the token and this latter was forwarded to the session callback, owtherwise the `token` and the `session` will never be updated

the `user` may be undefined sometimes inside the jwt callback when its value is not available yet

> Callbacks are **asynchronous** functions you can use to control what happens when an action is performed.

so if you look deeper in your logs you can see that the jwt callback was called twice and on the first call the user was defined.

However please tell that that the callbacks mentioned here in your code example are just for making the code shorther because the output you got with those empty callbacks is really confusing

Comment: Thanks for pointing out a potential direction where there might be an issue. You are right that it is present after compiling `/api/auth/[...nextauth] (client and server)...` and then in `compiling /(application)/app/feed/page (client and server)...` which uses the session call, `getServerSession`, after a successful login within a server-side component, the `user` is missing from the JWT Callback. I will likely open up a new question for this in particular

Comment: okay you are welcome, send me the link to your new question after you post it maybe I can help

Comment: Thank you for your consideration! Your explanation was extremely helpful and appreciated!

Comment: could you link the new question? i'm looking for an answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

for me the solution was to create

```
const newToken = {...token}
const newUser = {...user}
```

maybe it's a probleme of references idk